# cannot set popover bootstrap options using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have some trouble here...

lets say i have a element like this...

```
bootstrap(document).ready(function() {

       bootstrap('#popinquiry').popover({trigger:'hover'});
});
```

i using noConflict on my source code.. and then i have a element like this..

```
<a href='#' id='popinquiry' rel='popover' title='Popover Title'>heree</a>
```

and after i load the page.. the popover was shown, but the trigger i set above doesnt work.. so i must click the "heree" first too show my popover.. but when i write the trigger direct on 'popinquiry'

```
<a href='#' id='popinquiry' rel='popover' data-trigger='hover' title='Popover Title'>heree</a>
```

The option worked.. can you help me?? the problem is all off popover options parameter

Answer (score 0):

your javascript:

```
<script>  
$(function ()  
{ $('#popinquiry').popover();  
});  
</script>
```

your html :

```
<div class="well">  
<a href="#" id="popinquiry"  rel="popover" data-content="A simple tooltip for my awesome website" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code; I hope it will solve your problem:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".btn").popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement : 'bottom'
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="Popover content">Popover</a>
```

Further you can checkout this page for more working examples - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-popovers.php